# How to create limit marker lines in Silverlight 4 Chart

Tags: silverlight, charts

I'm creating LineSeries Sivlerlight chart to display changes of the system performance in real time.

The Y coordinate is numeric performance value, X is the date when this value was retrieved.

I need to add line that would represent upper limit for those values that are considered to be normal, so the user can easily see what limits have exceeded their limit and what limits haven't.

The line should also be in the chart legend. The line will be added dynamically from code during the retrieving of results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another line series to the chart that contains values for every date also present in your actual data series.  (You could do this by adding an additional property to the data objects representing the original data)

This value always has the same value so would draw a straight line.  The series title would appear in the legend.  You could style the data point for this series to prevent the small square data point shapes appearing on the line.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea. But I thought that silverlight ought to support this kind of stuff. Like DotNetCharting component have LimitMarksers collection that is being used to specify and display custom limits.

Comment: @Boris: There are zillions of things that "silverlight ought to support" but if it did how a big a download do think it would be?  How easy would it be to get it work the same on Mac as it does on Windows?  How expensive would it be to ensure that all these features aren't open to malicious manipulation?   I'd rather MS concentrate their efforts on stuff that can't be reasonably acheived with my own code rather than the making the "reasonable" even easier.

Comment: Agree even though limit markers are being supported by most chart components and I thought they may be supported by silver light charting component. I'll try your solution. Can you advice how i can change style of the line? Make it dotted?

Comment: @Boris: With regards to a dotted line do a little research on performance. I don't know the size of your applicaiton but within SL when you introduce a dotted line style it does impact the render engine and (requring more effort0. This could result in increased latency if you have a somewhat thick app. Here is a link that shows the xaml for a dotted line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929143/how-to-make-a-dotted-border-on-a-border-element-in-silverlight