# Control to pick one or more categories from a Category tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

### Example Class

```
class Category
{
    public List<Category> SubCategories;
    public Category()
    {
        this.SubCategories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

### Actual Content

Currently, i am creating an application in which a user needs to be able to select one or more categories for a given item.

For this purpose, i try to find an existing control that fits my requirements:

- supports Multi-Selection
- TreeView like displaying when expanded

right now, i am abusing a combobox for this with a margin for the items that just shifts the categories to the right the more the sublevel is:

```
Category1
    SubCategory1.1
    SubCategory1.2
        SubCategory1.2.1
        SubCategory1.2.N
    SubCategory1.N
Category2
    SubCategory2.1
CategoryN
```

however ... this is inconvenient when the category count grows large due to the list growing WAY too large.

Coding it myself would be possible, but due to me not knowing how to get the implementation using `Selector` as baseclass (or at least `ItemsControl`) properly with custom xxxxItem class (to save the different states etc.) i try to avoid this as it would mean to start at lowest level and implementing the eventing etc. myself.

Comment: TreeView with a checkbox in each item. In WinForms TreeView has checkboxes out-of-box. In wpf - [see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560466/how-to-make-wpf-treeview-style-as-winforms-treeview)

Comment: @ASh A ComboBox-like control is required, also i need to stay in WPF realms

Comment: "TreeView like displaying when expanded"-requirement doesn't sound to me like "A ComboBox-like control is required". WPF has TreeView control and it can be customized to have checkboxes like winforms TreeView - this statement means that you are staying in wpf realms

Comment: `right now, i am abusing a combobox` also wrote this but yes, missed that in my requirements :3

the approach you suggest seems to be fine at first glance but as far as i know it would require the categories objects to have a separate field that tells me if they are checked which is not possible thus requiring to build another tree with different objects refering to those objects

did i missed something out here or is that what you suggest? (just want to make sure i do not make myself more work then needed)