# Draw something in OnRender and using Background

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'd like to spruce up the WPF `TreeView` and add some functionality to it that needs to draw lines between the items of the `TreeView`. For that I created my own control inheriting from `TreeView` and drawing the lines in the `OnRender` override of that control:

```
Public Class MyTreeView
    Inherits TreeView

    Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(drawingContext As DrawingContext)
        MyBase.OnRender(drawingContext)

        drawingContext.DrawLine(New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), New Point(0, 0), New Point(Me.ActualWidth, Me.ActualHeight))
    End Sub

End Class
```

But I can only see my drawings in the running program, when I set the `Background` of my `TreeView` to `Transparent`.

```
<local:MyTreeView Background="Transparent" />
```

As soon as I put a white or gradient background to my `TreeView` it hides my drawings.

Is it possible to add some drawings in the `OnRender` override, that is rendered on top of the given `Background`?

For reasons that belong to another question I can't work with a transparent background and I can't work with a `Border` with background under a transparent `TreeView` simulating the background in the `TreeView`.

Comment: Have you tried using Blend and get the style for the tree view? Then just modify that style with your lines. `OnRender` sounds a bit hacky (like WinForms)

Comment: Since the size and amount of items in the `TreeView` isn't fixed I can't draw fixed lines in a `Style`, the count and position of the lines are dependent on the size and position of the items.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that the Tree View isn't designed to have indeterminate number of items? In WPF use styles, it will save you headache later in the development. WinForms is a thing of a past, just like stone tablets and chisels.

Comment: How should I put lines in a style, when I don't know how many lines and from where to where to draw the lines? Maybe you can enlighten me with a short example?

Comment: First [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19560467/2029607) in my google search. It is very comprehensive but if you need help, let us know.

Comment: So you want to put the lines into the items, not into the TreeView itself. Have to have a look in this. My items are arranged horizontally, not vertically, but I'll give it a try.