# How to add Scrolling to the HierarchicalDataTemplate items inside TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, virtualtreeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to add scrollviewer to every child inside TreeView. I can add scrollviewer for TreeView  but I cannot apply scrollviewer to children elements.
Here is my example of the structure what currently using

```
<TreeView x:Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TestTemplates}"
                                  DataType="{x:Type vm1:TestTemplateViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBlock}"/>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Test.png"
                           Visibility="true">
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

[image: Attached the mockup that I trying to get]

Comment: I think, you will have to modify TreeViewItem.Template to achieve that

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you describe in more detail your idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19560467/1506454: set MaxHeight for ItemsPresenter and put it in ScrollViewer. you should get vertical scroll bars if MaxHeight is exceeded

Comment: If I do something like so: 
<Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" MaxHeight="300" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </ControlTemplate>

                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter> my data disappearing and I got a lot of ScrollViewers

Comment: I something missing or I don't understand your suggestion?

Comment: you need everything else from linked temlated as well. and additional scrollviewer